# Extend every select query in the background

Tags: oracle, plsql

Is it possible to extend every select query which is executed by a db user?

e.g. the user will execute
`select * from mytable`
and in the background the following is executed:
`select * from mytable union all select * from different_schema.mytable`

It is possible to restrict a query by a dynamic where clause using VPD functions.

```
return '1=1'
```

Can I extend queries with VPD to also select data from different schemas?

```
return '1=1 union all select * from different_schema.' || tab;
```

I am getting the following error with the above example:

> ORA-28113: policy predicate has error

A workaround would be to create a bunch of dynamically generated views containing the unions, but I would like to use VPD or a similar approach if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can not do this with VPD. VPD will add a `predicate` to each query, which is an extension to the `where` clause of the query. It can not be used to `union` with another table.

I would suggest your other approach: use views that contain the unions and grant the appropriate rights on these views instead of the base table(s).